# Variable scoping in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

I have the following code:

```
var ids = new Array(5);
$(function(){
html5sql.process(sql, 
    function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
        for(var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++){
            ids[i] = rowsArray[i].ID;
                            console.log(ids[i]); //returns the actual value for i
        }
    },
    function(error, statement){
              console.log("Error: " + error.message);       
            }
);
console.log(ids[0]); //returns undefined
});
```

As you can see, the print out inside the for loop prints the correct value. On the other hand, when I print outside the function I get undefined. 
What is the problem with the scoping? How can I get the actual value of the array outside the function?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Those functions are callbacks. They are not invoked immediately.

Comment: How can I solve this problem. Can anyone please explain to me what is happening?

Comment: You are being told that the call to `html5sql.process()` runs asynchronously. The call to `console.log()` occurs immediately afterward and before any values are assigned to *ids*. You need to delay the call to *console.log* until processing is finished (and values have been assigned). I.e. you have a timing issue, not a scoping issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ids = [];

$( function () {

    html5sql.process( sql, function () {

        // LINE A: you are populating your array here

    });

    // LINE B: the array is still empty here

});
```

LINE A does appear above LINE B in the source code, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it executes sooner. That is because LINE A is inside a function expression which is passed into the `process` function. This `process` function will invoke that function expression at some time in the future.

So, basically, LINE B is executed immediately, and LINE A is executed at some point in the future. The function expression is probably bound (as a handler) to a SQL-related event.

Comment: I think your explanation is a bit flawed. The code is executed in order, but the function called by *html5sql()* is being run asynchronously (apparently) so it hasn't assigned values to *ids* when the call to *console.log* is made immediately afterward.

Comment: @RobG Could you be more specific? What statement from my answer is problematical?

Comment: The part that says `LINE A does appear above LINE B in the source code, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it executes sooner`. The code is executed in sequence, but the function it calls is asynchroonous so it's still executing when the next line is called.

Comment: @RobG My statement is correct. LINE A is not executed immediately, and LINE B is executed immediately. Therefore LINE B is executed sooner (in time) than LINE A. As a matter of fact, from the code provided by the OP, he have **no guarantee** that LINE A is executed at all. When the statement `html5sql.process(...);` executes, the function expression is passed into the `process` function - the function body of that function expression is **not** executed at this point. It's up to the `process` function to decide if it wants to invoke that function immediately...

Comment: ...or bind it as an event handler so that it's invoked when an event triggers at some point in the future. Therefore, my statement - *"LINE A does appear above LINE B in the source code, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it executes sooner (in time)"* - is correct.

Comment: @RobG And if I may correct your statement while I'm at it. You say "*...but the function it calls is asynchronous so it's still executing when the next line is called.*". This is not possible. JavaScript execution is single-threaded, so it's not possible for a function to "be still executing" while another statement is executed. There are two possibilities: (1) The function expression has been invoked immediately (inside `process`), and by the time LINE B is executed, the function has already returned, or...

Comment: ... (2) the function expression has not been invoked immediately, so by the time LINE B is executed, the function has not yet been invoked (its function body has not yet been executed).

Comment: Your answer might be construed to mean that script statements may be processed in any order. Nowhere do you say that *html5sql.process()* returns immediately while the code within it is processed asynchronously, which is the OP's problem. Probably also worth pointing out that work on the [Web SQL Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) specificaion was stopped over a year ago and is being replaced by [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) and [Indexed Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).